# NoReverseMatch at /watchlist/view_watchlist

Tags: django, django-models

Iam trying to remove objects from the watchlist of my movie project and this error comes when i click the option.

**Error message**

```
[07/Jul/2023 11:47:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6331
Internal Server Error: /watchlist/view_watchlist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "G:\1.PycharmProjects\project\movie db\watchlist\views.py", line 11, in watchlist
    return render(request,'watchlist.html',{'watchlist':watchlist})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 238, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 471, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_watchlist' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['watchlist/delete_watchlist/(?P<dslug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']
[07/Jul/2023 11:47:31] "GET /watchlist/view_watchlist HTTP/1.1" 500 178458
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from watchlist.models import Watchlist
admin.site.register(Watchlist)
```

**This is my Watchlist model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from movie.models import Movie

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=User)
    movie = models.OneToOneField(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    date_added=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie.name
```

I tried to get the object by slug
**address**

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" href="{% url 'watchlist:delete_watchlist' i.slug %}">Remove</a>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from watchlist import views
app_name='watchlist'
urlpatterns = [
    # function based path
    path('delete_watchlist/<slug:dslug>',views.delete_watchlist,name='delete_watchlist'),
]
```

This is the views module
**views.py**

```
def delete_watchlist(request,dslug):
    m=Watchlist.objects.get(slug=dslug)
    m.delete()
    return watchlist(request)
```

This is the watchlist template
**watchlist.html**

```
<div class="container">
    {% for i in watchlist %}
    <div class="card card-bordered border-dark mt-3" style="width:750px;" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
<!--                <img src="{{i.movie.poster.url}}" style="height:200px; width:145px;">-->
                <a href="#"><img src="{{i.movie.poster.url}}" style="height:220px; width:145px;"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h4 class="title">{{i.movie.name}}</h4>
                <strong class="title">{{i.movie.year}}</strong>
                <p class="title"><img src="{% static 'img/imdb.png' %}" style="height:auto; width:30px;"> {{i.movie.rating}}</p>
                <p class="title">{{i.movie.certification}}</p>
                Added on : {{i.date_added}}<br>
                <a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" href="{% url 'watchlist:delete_watchlist' i.slug %}">Remove</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

It used to work before, but after i made some changes it getting errors,
How can i solve this .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line `<a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" href="{% url 'watchlist:delete_watchlist' i.slug %}">Remove</a>` should be like this :

`<a class="btn btn-small btn-primary" href="{% url 'watchlist:delete_watchlist' i.dslug %}">Remove</a>`
infact you must pass the slug name that you use in your function, I mean you use **dslug** in your fucntion and so you should use it in your **href** too. try it  out.

Answer (score 0):

the error tells that i.slug is empty in

```
.... href="{% url 'watchlist:delete_watchlist' i.slug %}"
```

either you have a model instance without slug or it is a problem of the context created in watchlist() view

Also interesting: Watchlist model has no slug field.